# Compare two datetime fields in the select statement - TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have this sql select query:

```
declare @godina as integer = 2020

select 

vtRokSi.KodSI, 
vtRokSi.rKod,
vtRokSi.rDatum, 
vtRokSi.rDatumZavr,
CONVERT(datetime, vtRokSi.rDatum) as docni
-- if CONVERT(datetime, vtRokSi.rDatum) > vtRokSi.rDatumZavr
-- select 'docni' as docni
-- else if CONVERT(datetime, vtRokSi.rDatum) <= vtRokSi.rDatumZavr
-- select 'ne docni' as docni
-- else if vtRokSi.rDatumZavr
-- select 'nema vneseno'

from GP.dbo.VT_ROK_SI as vtRokSi

where vtRokSi.GodGP = @godina
```

where you can see, that I am trying to compare two columns. 
vtRokSi.rDatum is of type date and vtRokSi.rDatumZavr is of type datetime. I am converting vtRokSi.rDatum to datetime.

I want to print several values in the column 'docni', for example, 
the string 'nema vneseno' if vtRokSi.rDatumZavr is null, 
'docni' if vtRokSi.rDatum is bigger then vtRokSi.rDatumZavr, 
'ne docni' if vtRokSi.rDatum is smaller or equal to vtRokSi.rDatumZavr.

How can I do that in the same select statement?

Or will I need something more powerful, i.e. separate the command into several other?

Comment: If seems like you're after a `CASE` expression. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression.

```
...
CASE
  WHEN vtroksi.rdatum > vtroksi.rdatumzavr THEN
    'docni'
  WHEN vtroksi.rdatum <= vtroksi.rdatumzavr THEN
    'ne docni'
  ELSE
    'nema vneseno'
END docni
...
```

Comment: Hmm, totally forgot about case. Is that the right way to compare datetime fields? Or will I get compilation error?

Comment: @Vlad: I cannot really follow. You get an error? What does it say?